# Configure ambient media player source code in my eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

Im trying to see working of ambient media player.

I checkout from url https://ambientmp.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ambientmp/Ambient/trunk  to my eclipse work space. when build the app it is showing errors as

- Unbound classpath variable: 'M2_REPO/hotsax/hotsax/0.1/hotsax-0.1.jar' in project 'ambient'
- Unbound classpath variable: 'M2_REPO/net/sf/entagged/entagged/0.31/entagged-0.31.jar' in project 'ambient'

please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the .classpath file in the project, and need to find those jars if they are not included in the repository anywhere and have your project properly reference them.

Comment: hi jrl, I donot find jars in repository, and I google for jars which is showing in .classpath, bt not able to find out. <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/hotsax/hotsax/0.1/hotsax-0.1.jar" sourcepath="/M2_REPO/hotsax/hotsax/0.1/hotsax-0.1-sources.jar"/> <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sf/entagged/entagged/0.31/entagged-0.31.jar" sourcepath="/M2_REPO/net/sf/entagged/entagged/0.31/entagged-0.31-sources.jar"/> Please tell me how i can work out this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need Maven 2

`apt-get install maven2`

then you need to do this

`mvn -Declipse.workspace=YOUR_WORKSPACE_PATH eclipse:add-maven-repo`

then you need to track down these jar files: `hotsax-0.1.jar` and `entagged-0.31.jar`

I'm trying to get ambient going as well, but so far it's not that fun.

Comment: you also need to go through the `strings.xml` files and modify the occurrences of `%s` with `%1$s`, `%2$s`,`...`,`%n$s` if there's more than 1 occurrence in a single string.